# Performing merge in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, merge

By means of the PostgreSQL/PostGIS I want to replicate a function from a Python script into a SQL query. In my Python script, I have a list of feature classes and I use ArcPy's `Merge_Management` to merge them together into a new layer called `s_stud`:

```
study_lyr_list = ["region_1", "region_2", "region_3"]
arcpy.Merge_management(studies_lyr_list, s_studs)
```

I essentially have the same thing setup in PostGIS. I have tables for regions 1, 2, and 3 and I want to merge them together. They all share the same fields, so basically, I am just combining them together into a new `master` table.

How would I do that as a query?

I have the PostGIS extensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [UNION or UNION ALL](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-union/), depending on whether you want duplicates. Example:

```
SELECT f1,f2,f3
FROM t1

UNION 

SELECT f1,f2,f3
FROM t2
```

Assuming the structure is exact across all three tables, the schema you're using is `public`, the geometry field is called `geom` and fields are ordered the same way:

```
CREATE TABLE public.master AS 
SELECT * FROM region_1
UNION
SELECT * FROM region_2
UNION
SELECT * FROM region_3;

ALTER TABLE public.master ADD COLUMN gid serial4 PRIMARY KEY;
CREATE INDEX master_idx on public.master using GIST(geom);
```

You may have to write out the field names in case fields aren't ordered in the same way, or if you want to skip some fields. Creating your primary key field using `serial4` rather than the default `serial8` will avoid some issues ArcGIS has in reading PostgreSQL primary key fields. Both ArcGIS and QGIS require tables or views to have a field that passes for a valid unique identifier.

[Other useful query combination operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-union.html):

> EXCEPT - select every value from the first query except those that
> appear in the second query.
>
> INTERSECT - select every value from the first query that also appears in
> the second query.

Comment: Actually, that part about `row_number()` in views is *awful* advice, at least as far as ArcGIS goes. It can cause selection set and identify operations to fail horrifically. Best practice is to make the rowid column an actual column.

Comment: As a FOSS guy, it's hard to keep track of ESRI's many bugs.

Comment: But thanks for that comment,  @Vince.  Will keep that in mind

Comment: I'm getting an error `Syntax error at or near TABLE` near the `ALTER TABLE` part.

Comment: ALTER TABLE master ADD COLUMN gid serial4 PRIMARY KEY; <- is correct. Are you running both the table creation and the alter queries at once, and if so, do you have a semicolon separating them? I would run them separately if you get that syntax error. But there's nothing wrong with the ALTER TABLE syntax in the answer. Also, I'd add a schema before the table name just as good practice, i.e. public.master if the table is in the public schema.

Comment: I think it was the missing schema that was causing it. Works great; exactly what I was looking for.